# Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED))

Tags: windows, powershell, windows-server-2016

I have a script where part of it looks for pending updates on workstations in the domain. It iterates the following code over all computer members.

```perl
$Command = (((New-Object -ComObject Microsoft.Update.Session).CreateupdateSearcher()).Search("IsInstalled=0")).updates  
$Updates = Invoke-Command -ComputerName $Com -Credential $Cred -ScriptBlock {$Command}
```

But when I run the code (on the DC server locally by just running `$Command` or remotely by running `$Updates`), I get the following error:

```
Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED))
    + CategoryInfo          : OperationStopped: (:) [], UnauthorizedAccessException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.UnauthorizedAccessException
    + PSComputerName        : SERVER_NAME
```

I have also tried to run the code locally but gets the same error.

### P.S.

I knwo that there is a problem with permissions but I do not know where should I fix it. By the way, I prefer fixing the issue in Powershell not by changing GPO or other settings. I want to make my script unattended.

Comment: Are you sure the user that is running the code has administrative privileges on the domain controller?  When you ran it locally, did you start Powershell with the "as administrator" option?

Comment: @HarryJohnston Yes, I have checked it several times.

Comment: I tried the command on one of my domain controllers and it worked, so there might be something wrong with your DC.  Does Windows Update work from the control panel?

Comment: @HarryJohnston Thanks, I guess so. As I am writing a script, I would like to see the possible issues in the script to show a resonable error. When I can not understand something, then others can't too :)